# What nodes are used in aggregation and reduction for reduce?

Tags: apache-spark

I am curious how the `reduce(f: (T, T) => T): T` function in Spark works.

When I have X nodes processing data and then aggregating the resultant data through the use of `reduce`, how exactly does the aggregation work? How many nodes are involved in aggregation and reduction?

By *nodes* I mean the driver and the executors of a Spark application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking one step deeper in the code, you will find the following note:

```
 /**
   * Reduces the elements of this RDD using the specified commutative and
   * associative binary operator.
   */
  def reduce(f: (T, T) => T): T
```

The restrictions on the function are important to ensure that `reduce` will work correctly. 
As for 'how it works', `reduce` will be applied locally to each partition and the result of that will be reduced together to achieve a final result.

So, X nodes holding data will all execute the `reduce` operation in parallel and the result of that will be aggregated together on the driver node. Provided that the function is commutative and associative will ensure a stable result (that is, independent of the order how the function is applied to the data)

A simplified example:

Given an rdd with 3 partitions each on one executor:

```
rdd = 

p1 - [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
p2 - [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
p3 - [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Then `rdd.reduce(_ + _)`:

```
+-------+---------- stage1-------------------+to driver+------------------------+
| EX1   | [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 ].reduce(_ + _) | => 36   |                        |
| EX2   | [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13].reduce(_ + _) | => 41   |                        |
| EX3   | [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8  ].reduce(_ + _) | => 20   |                        |
| Driver|                                    |         | (36,41,20).reduce(_+_) | 
+-------+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
```

The same can be observed on the Spark log after the execution of such simple action:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 15,3)
rdd.reduce(_ + _)

TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 3 tasks
TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1220 bytes)
TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1220 bytes)
TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1220 bytes)
Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4)
Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3)
Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5)
Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4). 727 bytes result sent to driver
Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3). 727 bytes result sent to driver
Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5). 727 bytes result sent to driver
TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) in 4 ms on localhost (1/3)
TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) in 6 ms on localhost (2/3)
TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5) in 6 ms on localhost (3/3)
DAGScheduler: Stage 1 (reduce at <console>:14) finished in 0.007 s
TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: reduce at <console>:14, took 0.014196 s
```

Comment: Just because the function says commutative and associate doesn't mean that it has to be all aggregated and computed on the driver node. It could still have intermediate level(s) that contain nodes that each aggregate part of the overall combined output, reduce the data, and forward it up to upper levels.